Show PDF Thumbnails on GNOME Desktop
My PDF thumbnails on the desktop have reverted to Adobe icons.
I have Evince installed and I am confident that the thumbnails are being generated because thumbnails show up in the Nautilus window for the desktop folder.
Two out of a dozen or more thumbnails are displayed on the desktop, as in this screenshot, so there's hope that something is working correctly, just not everything. One pdf link displays a thumbnail, one an icon.

I tried clearing out the thumbnail cache. They regenerate perfectly and display in Nautilus, but not on the desktop.
I tried switching my default PDF reader from Evince/Document View to Okular (my preferred viewer) and back with reboots in between.
This used to work fine, and stopped working after updates.
I am running Ubuntu 24.10 on a Dell XPS 13 and everything is up to date. I'm not a newbie but I'm not deeply into the technical details, so please give suggestion without assuming too much technical knowledge here.
